# Neural network converging to average aswer

Tags: c#, deep-learning, neural-network

I have made a Neural network in C# using ReLu in the hidden layers and Sigmoids in the outer layers. I am trying to train it to learn if `input0^3 > input1` but for some reason it refuses to learn and instead randomly guesses `false` or `53.1% sure it's true`.

I have tried to play around with the learing rate (not 0.03), with the amount of iterations (now 1000) and with the size of its brain (it now has 2 inputs, 4,5,3 hidden nodes and 1 output). None of these have seemed to change much except maybe the number it platoes at.

I train the network by increasing, decreasing or just leaving a weight/bias alone depending on what performs better.

```cs
// Current settings
int[] dimensions = {2, 4, 5, 3, 1};
const double trainDelta = 0.03;
const int trainingIterations = 1000;
... // In the tweaker
if (best == lowerError) return;
if (best == originalError) network.Tweak(delta, layer, node, postion);
else network.Tweak(2*delta, layer, node, postion);
...// How I get my correct answers
return y > Math.Pow(x, 3) ? 1 : 0;
... // My activation function
double output = bias;
for (int i = 0; i < inputs; i++)
    output += weights[i] * input[i];
if (type != NodeType.HiddenNode) return(1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-output))); // Sigmoid
if (output > 0) return output; // ReLu
return 0;
```

Does anyone know what I could try to make it actually learn something?

Comment: I think this is a rounding issue with integers and floats.   Solution may be to use Math.Floor and Math.Ceil to get around the rounding issue.  To test for an integer use if(number = Match.floor(number))

Comment: Where do you think I need to put those? I don't really see anywhere where I am converting my `double`s to `int`s?

Comment: You should be getting 50% ones and zeroes. Not 53%. You are not getting equal to work due to rounding. So you instead are returning y > Math.Pow(x, 3) ? 1 : 0; So maybe instead use x < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;

Comment: The correct answer is `y > Math.Pow(x, 3) ? 1 : 0`, it gives 1 or `true` if `(x,y)` is above the graph `y = x^3` and 0, `false` otherwise. This is not a rounding function, this is the function I want the network to learn. At the moment my network's output is either `0.00` or `0.53`, all my network has ever done is output a mix of `0.00` and some constant dependant on my network size.